# Find files that contain string match1 but does not contain match2

Tags: bash, file, shell, grep

I am writing a shell script to find files which contain string "match1" AND does not contain "match2".

I can do this in 2 parts:

1. grep -lr "match1" * > /tmp/match1
2. grep -Lr "match2" * > /tmp/match2
3. comm -12 /tmp/match1 /tmp/match2

Is there a way I can achieve this directly without going through the process of creating temporary files ?

Answer (score 2):

I would use find together with `awk`. `awk` can check both matches in a single run, meaning you don't need to process all the files twice:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec awk '/match1/{m1=1}/match2/{m2=1} END {if(m1 && !m2){print FILENAME}}' {} \;
```

Better explained in multiline version:

```
# Set flag if match1 occurs
/match1/{m1=1}

# Set flag if match2 occurs
/match2/{m2=1}

# After all lines of the file have been processed print the
# filename if match1 has been found and match2 has not been found.
END {if(m1 && !m2){print FILENAME}}
```

Comment: You'd need to reset the variables and print the prev FILENAME in `FNR==1` blocks for it to work on more than 1 file. Using ENDFILE with GNU awk instead of END can make it simpler.

Comment: Good point. I admit that I've tested only with a single file.

Comment: Have not so much time to change the answer atm. Used the help of `find`, while awk could even do it alone using the `FNR==1` method you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

With bash's [process substitution](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC35):

```
comm -12 <(grep -lr "match1" *)  <(grep -Lr "match2" *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='^$' '/match1/ && !/match2/ {print FILENAME}' *
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can achieve this directly without going through the process of creating temporary files ?

Yes.  You can use pipelines and `xargs`:

```
grep -lr "match1" * | xargs grep -Lr "match2"
```

The first `grep` prints the names of files containing matches to its standard output, as you know.  The `xargs` command reads those file names from its standard input, and converts them into arguments to the second `grep` command, appending them after the ones already provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can initially search for the files containing match1 and then using `xargs`pass it to other grep using `-L` or `--files-without-match` option.

```
grep -lr "match1" *|xargs grep -L "match2"
```